# Auto Line break for Label in JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx, scenebuilder

I want to add Labels inside 160x170 sized boxes(AnchorPane for example). But when text is too long for its container, overflow will be hidden instead of turning into multi-line. I want to be able to manage Labels both in Java code and FXML [like I did with Web's CSS](https://aliihsansenel.github.io/stackoverflow.html).[codes are included]

I've also tried to change Label's height, width, and padding but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#setWrapText(boolean)

Have you enabled the wrapping feature?